# Alternative to calling models in the views - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

Trying to improve the code of my app and just migrated to L5. I used to call models in my views and I know this is not best practice - I should separate data calling and views completely. 
However how do you deal with a situation like this:

```
          <div class="field">
            <label for="country">Country<sup>*</sup></label>
            <select class="" id="country" name="country">
              <option value="{{{ old('country') ? old('country') : '' }}}">{{{ old('country') ? App\Country::find(old('country'))->country_name : '' }}}</option>
              @foreach ($countries as $studio_country)
              <option value="{{ e($studio_country->id) }}">{{ e($studio_country->country_name) }}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
            @if ($errors->has('country'))
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
              {{ $errors->first('country') }}
            </div>
            @endif
            <br>
          </div>
```

Basically if there is an input and the input did not pass the validation the page refreshes with the old input and the error message. I need to extract the name of the country from the DB since I only have its ID.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like this:

```
 <select id="country" name="country">
     @foreach ($countries as $studio_country)
          <option 
              value="{{ $studio_country->id }}"
              {{ $studio_country->id === old('country') ? 'selected' : '' }}>
              {{ $studio_country->country_name }}
          </option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
```